# Ongoing animation on multiple .html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've got an amazing navbar design (in my opinion). But there’s one problem! When I add other .html pages het animation isn’t showing on the next .html page. I know that the browser does not remember previous activity on the page before so the animation resets... Is there a way I can apply the animation on all 4 .html pages? So when clicking contact it will swipe to contact and stays on contact and does not reset to the default first one?

```
<div class="main">
<a href="#about"><span class="menu m1">ABOUT</span>
<a href="#contact"><span class="menu m2">CONTACT</span>
<a href="#home"><span class="menu logo">
    <img src="TBGFXLOGO2019NBG.png" width="100px"/>
</span>
<a href="#portfolio"><span class="menu m3">PORTFOLIO</span>
<a href="#order"><span class="menu m4">ORDER</span>
<span class="active"/>
```

```
    body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #232323;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Stroud';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.active {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.m1 {
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: initial;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}   



$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".m1").click(function(){
            $(".m1").css({'color':'black'});
            $(".m2, .m3, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
            $(".active").css({'left':'0px','transform':'skewX(20deg)'});
        });
        $(".m2").click(function(){
            $(".m2").css({'color':'black'});
            $(".m1, .m3, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
            $(".active").css({'left':'100px','transform':'skewX(20deg)'});
        });
        $(".m3").click(function(){
            $(".m3").css({'color':'black'});
            $(".m1, .m2, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
            $(".active").css({'left':'359px','transform':'skewX(-20deg)'});
        });
        $(".m4").click(function(){
            $(".m4").css({'color':'black'});
            $(".m1, .m2, .m3").css({'color':'white'});
            $(".active").css({'left':'461px','transform':'skewX(-20deg)'});
        });
    });
```

Comment: Use Ajax to load the content not reloading the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should get #hash from your url, once link is clicked. Than in your JS you compare your hash with your menu items. When these two are the same, add class to menu item, like active or so, and give active class any animation you want.

```
//TO GET THE HASH VIA JS
$(".main a").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(".main a").each(function(){
 var curr = $(this);
if (hash == $(this).attr("href")) {
   $("span", curr).addClass("active");
 }})
}
```